# How can I leverage django models in an asyncio co-routine launched within a celery task?

Tags: postgresql, celery, python-3.6, python-asyncio, django-2.1

I've refactored some django code to do some web scraping.  I launch a separate Celery Task for each User that I'm doing data scraping for.  Within each Celery task, I'm using asyncio and aiohttp to do the scraping for a given User.

I can access all of my django model classes, and methods, but as soon as I do something to trigger an actual database query, I get an error like:

```
...
[2019-02-16 18:04:38,126] WARNING log /home/chrisadmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py:561: RuntimeWarning: Exception raised outside body: OperationalError('SSL SYSCALL error: Bad file descriptor\n',):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chrisadmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL SYSCALL error: Socket operation on non-socket
...
```

Within the Celery Tasks, I can do things that cause Django to interact with the database without any problems as long as they don't involve asyncio.  Likewise, I can successfully interact with the database through Django in asyncio tasks as long as those asyncio Tasks aren't in turn launched from within a Celery Task.

If I set `CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER=True` I don't get the exceptions, but of course Celery Tasks aren't running concurrently in that case.

For scraping a single user, asyncio/aiohttp are more than sufficient.  But I want to use Celery to be able to scale out across processes/machines and scrape multiple users in parallel.  Previously I had tried to use Celery exclusively but I've tried to refactor with asyncio/aiohttp to reduce overhead where it's not necessary.

I want to be able to use Celery to launch scraping for multiple users in parallel and then within each Celery Task, I want to be able to scrape the respective Users, inclusive of saving their scraped data via django models/methods.

Answer (score 0):

After some further investigation, it appears as if there's an issues with the database connections and possible thread safety when combining asyncio and celery that I don't fully understand.

The solution that seems to be working so far was to create a new function:

```
from django.db import connections
from django.conf import settings


def reset_db_connections():
    if not settings.CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER:
        connections.close_all()
```

I call this function as the first line of any celery task:

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def my_celery_task(self, args):
    reset_db_connections()
    # do stuff
    # call stuff that uses asyncio
```

So far, this seems to allow my code to work regardless of what setting I have for `CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER`.

Initially instead of `connections.close_all()` I tried:

```
 for conn in db.connections.all():
     if conn.connection.closed != 0:
         conn.connection.close()
```

but that caused errors where either I wasn't closing connections that needed to be closed and/or I was closing connections that were already closed.

As an alternative to the above solution, I found that changing the setting:

`DATABASES = {"default": dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)}`

to

`DATABASES = {"default": dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=0)}`

also resolved the issue.  However, as I understand it, setting `conn_max_age=0` would use a new connection for every db operation which doesn't seem like a great idea.  With the `reset_db_connections()` approach above, I can leave `conn_max_age=600`.